# Cassandra Timeseries: Compress infrequently changing fields

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I need to store time stamped vehicle location along with reverse geocoded address and some simple numeric sensor values for each entry.

The reverse geocoded address is anywhere between 100 to 200 bytes and about 4kb if I store alternative addresses and other metadata the reverse geocoder returns. Most of the time, the address does not change in successive records. I was wondering if it is possible for Cassandra to compress such infrequently changing values. Similarly other sensor values such as temperature, pressure etc don't change that often.

I had briefly tried using InfoBright's column store engine for MySQL several years ago. One of its claims was that it compresses infrequently changing fields very well.

Can something like this be done with Cassandra? I read some articles that make me think yes. If that is the case, it is a killer feature as most time series data involving sensors has lot of scope for run length compression. But the general lack of excitement around that topic in articles I came across makes me feel that the benefits are not that much in practice. Or they simply don't have data with long runs of repeating data like I do. The reported compression ratios were about 4x. I am expecting at least 10x based on a simple RLE. But since Cassandra has better algos than RLE, I'm hoping to achieve a much larger compression ratio.

I am reading all about Cassandra and will be doing these tests myself soon. But it would be great if someone can share their two cents.